# String to Time with parser not working on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, parsing, time

Well I am very new on ruby, first program, running on Eclipse and Windows, and simply can't make it read or debug well. It does not read console while I debug.
Help!

```
require 'time'

#defining limitations on arrays
Day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
Number = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,0]]
timeFromM = Time.new(2010, 03, nil, 7)
timeToM = Time.new(2020, 12, nil, 9, 30)
timeFromE = Time.new(2010, 03, nil, 16)
timeToE = Time.new(2020, 12, nil, 19, 30)
range1 = timeFromM..timeToM
range2 = timeFromE..timeToE

#movement allowance
def carOnTheRoad (plateNumber, dateRoad, timeRoad)
  $i = Day.length
  date = dateRoad + timeRoad
  time = Time.parse(date)
  print time
  plateEnd = plateNumber[plateNumber.length-1]
  while $i > 0  do
    if date.strftime("%A")==Day[$i] && Number[$i]==plateEnd && range1===time && range2===time
        puts("Car can't be on the road")
    else
        puts("Car can be on the road")
    end
    $i -=1
  end
end

#interacting with user
print "Please enter your Plate Number <Ex: PXX0000>"
plate = gets.chomp
print "Please enter the date <DD/MM/YYYY>"
date = gets.chomp
print "Please enter the time <24:59>"
time = gets.chomp
carOnTheRoad(plate, date, time)
```

And this is the console output:

```
Please enter your Plate Number <Ex: PXX0000>PZZ0990
Please enter the date <DD/MM/YYYY>26/08/2016
Please enter the time <24:59>8:30
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:302:in `local': argument out of range (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:302:in `make_time'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb:366:in `parse'
```

Comment: use `strptime` function for parsing Time http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error has to do with the line `date = dateRoad + timeRoad`

```
dateRoad = 26/08/2016
timeRoad = 8:30
```

When you add them out, you get

```
date = '26/08/20168:30'
```

That is why you get an out of range error.

What you need is to add a space between the two values.

```
date = dateRoad + " " + timeRoad #=> '26/08/2016 8:30'
```

Now there is a new error

> undefined method `strftime' for "26/08/2016 8:30":String

I'm going to assume `strftime` is a function you defined.

Comment: strftime should give me the day of that date, that's why the %A

Comment: maybe it was the site i was using. `strftime` is an actual function. But adding that space between `dateRoad` and `timeRoad` should fix your error.

Comment: d.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y")   #=> "Printed on 11/19/2007" this is on the documentation.

Comment: i found it too. it does exist. All i'm saying is it didn't work on the site i was using. that's all.

Comment: seems like     time = Time.parse(date)    this is not doing it's job

Comment: BTW do you know why my debug is not working :/ it willl be easier